# Where should enums live in an MVC project structure?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, domain-driven-design

I'm using .NET MVC 3 Code-First approach. My domain have a entity called `Question`, this entity have a `Score` property that is `Byte` and I want to replace that property to an `Enum` and name this `Enum` to `Score` where I can set the values from 0 to 10.

Where should Enums live in that structure? In a folder called **Enums** in my **Model** folder?

**Update:**

That's my project Structure in **Models** folder:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a value object. I'd put it in the same place you put other value objects in your domain, which really depends on your folder structure. Definitely in the Model folder, but if you're subdividing the model folder, it depends on how you're doing that. Do you have a Q&A subfolder? Maybe it goes there next to questions. Or do you have a Value Objects subfolder? Maybe there.

Comment: In that case I'd create a new Value Objects subfolder and put it there.

Answer (score 9):

What you really should be concerned about is the *namespace* of your enums.

Regardless of where your class file exists in the solution, your code will rely on the namespaces. I'm thinking that you'd probably want a namespace like: `Questiona2011.Enums` . It won't be a good idea to tie the Enum classes to the `Models` namespace - not that it can't be done, but sometimes the views may need to interact with your enums. So I tend to give my enums a separate namespace.

You don't necessarily need to create a folder for the class file... you can keep in in the root directory if you'd like - The real factor is the namespace.

So create a class with the namespace like so:

```
using System;

namespace Questiona2011.Enums
{
    public enum Score
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        .
        .
        .
        Ten = 10
    }
}
```

Having said that, I'd just drop the class file in the Models folder. :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a better place to put them, I stick them in the Model folder.

If you have a lot of Enums though, you might want to do the folder idea that you were doing. I don't think I would call it "enums" though as that's not very descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is getting large enough to be concerned about organization, you should consider creating a new Project that is just a DLL for your applications' types.